# Where can I find some documentation on NSTextStorage editedMask?

Tags: cocoa, nstextstorage

The [NSTextStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/index.html) documentation mentions the `editedMask` which according to the docs:

```
Returns the kinds of edits pending for the receiver
```

However, I cannot seem to find any bit flags for this mask anywhere (either in the docs or in the `NSTextStorage` api. Does anyone know where I can find the details of this mask? (I have also search stackoverflow and while I find questions referencing the use of the mask, I still cannot find the bit definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a bitmask of the values from the `NSTextStorageEditedOptions` enum: `NSTextStorageEditedAttributes` and/or `NSTextStorageEditedCharacters`.